# Flask migration error

Tags: python, flask, alembic

I've got an application build on flask and I wanted to create a new migration for it today. When I run         `$python manage.py db upgrade`

i got the message

raise util.CommandError('Only a single head is supported. The '
alembic.util.CommandError: Only a single head is supported. The script directory has multiple heads (due to branching), which must be resolved by manually editing the revision files to form a linear sequence. Run `alembic branches` to see the divergence(s).

So i run this command       `$alembic branches`
  No config file 'alembic.ini' found, or file has no '[alembic]' section

Any clue on what is this about?

Answer (score 0):

The error messages are coming from alembic, so they use the command form `alembic <command>`, but your integrating with Flask is coming from Flask-Migrate, so you need to use the form `python manage.py db branches`.

To resolve multiple branches, make one of the branches point down to the other branch so that the upgrade graph is a straight line.

- See alembic's docs on branches: http://alembic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/branches.html